# Laravel forge server disconnected

Tags: laravel, laravel-forge

We received the following error when connecting to the server:

```
WHEN CONNECTING AS "root" USER:
```

with Digitalocean droplet

### Error Output

```
Server Disconnected

We had trouble connecting to your server. Typically, this means there is a problem with the SSH keys on the server. Or, your server may be prompting for a password when Forge attempts to SSH in as the root user.


Recently reset the root password? If you have recently reset your root password via the DigitalOcean control card, this will break Forge's access to your server. You must SSH into your server and set a new password for the root user.

We received the following error when connecting to the server:

WHEN CONNECTING AS "root" USER:

Please make sure that the following SSH key is placed in both the /home/forge/.ssh/authorized_keys file and the /root/.ssh/authorized_keys file on your server.
```